# What this is doing to the require statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm exploring with NodeJS and I've stumble upon the following syntax using the express debug module:

```
require('debug')(express:server);
```

What is it? I've never see this form before and doesn't really find a way to google it to retrieve information on it.

Does this form allow a sort of argument passing to the load module statement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting `(some, arguments)` after something that evaluates as a value does the same thing it does everywhere else. It calls that value as a function.

---

This is a function expression:

```
(function () { })
```

It evaluates as a function and you can call it:

```
(function () { })()
```

This is a function that returns a function:

```
function foo () {
    return function () { };
}
```

You can call it to get a function:

```
foo();
```

and that evaluates as a function so you can call that function immediately:

```
foo()();
```

This is a module that returns a function:

```
module.exports = function () {}
```

You can require it to get a function:

```
require("myModule")
```

And you can call that function immediately:

```
require("myModule")()
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir! I don't know why I didn't think of require as a function and so consequently didn't thought about a function returning another function.